# Python ReportLab library ability to change PDF DA string?

Tags: python, string, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

I was able to make use of reportlabs textAnnotation function, however I have no ability to modify the default appearance string of the text annotation.
I have looked at the source code,

https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/d3a68f4690c23e1726b997acd62011358ef1a636/src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

and I saw that for the freeTextAnnotation function there is an option to update the default appearance string. I have not been able to get this to work though. I've tried adding the same 'DA' dictionary option to the textAnnotation function in the source code, but when I went to declare the string it did not work.

Also according to Adobe's PDF 1.7 reference, the DA string is a required string for text annotations. Without declaring this string the responsibility is left to the pdf reader to declare the string, which can sometimes lead to reading errors.

Currently all I have is this and it is working but the annotation occurs in black color when I need it to be red.

```
c.textAnnotation('hello', Rect=[10, 10, 20, 20])
```

To ask this question in simpler terms, how do I change the appearance color of a text annotation in reportlab? Neither setFillColorRGB nor setStrokeColorRGB effect the color of the annotation in reportlab.

Also, another question I have yet to find the answer to is, is It possible to create layers in a pdf using reportlab or pypdf2? From what I've read so far it seems that this functionality isn't available, but if anyone has been able to do so successfully please let me know.

Thanks.